# Trouble printing hex values with vector using printf

Tags: c++, vector, printf, uint32-t

My issue is simple:

```
uint32_t memory::read_word1 (uint32_t address) {
  if(address>(maxWord)){
        return 0;
    }
    uint32_t temp = 10; 
    return temp; 


}

uint32_t memory::read_word2 (uint32_t address) {
      if(address>(maxWord)){
            return 0;
        }

        return mem[address];

    }

void memory::show_address (uint32_t address) {
    int temp=read_word(address);
    printf("%08jx\n", (uintmax_t)temp);
}

// Write a word of data to an address, mask contains 1s for bytes to be updated
void memory::write_word (uint32_t address, uint32_t data, uint32_t mask) {
    if(address>(maxWord)){
        int newMax = ceil(address/1024)*1024;
        for(int i=maxWord+1;i<=newMax;i++){
            mem.push_back(0);
        }
        maxWord=newMax;
    }

    data=data&mask;
    mem[address]=data&~mask;
    mem[address]=mem[address]|data;
}
```

read_word1 and 2 return the value to be printed through show_address. read_word2 is the function that we desire. However, the problem we find is that when we return from the vector using `mem[address]`; read_word1 will print `0000000a` while read_word2 prints `00000010` when we set an element to 10 (via write_word).

To solve this I have tried using mem.at(address), type casting and even converting to string, all to no avail. The vector `mem` is defined as

```
   std::vector<uint32_t> mem=decltype(mem)(1024,0);
```

in the class header file.

It seems this is an underlying problem with the vector- what can be done?

**EDIT:**

Thanks everybody for your help. Feeling like the topic has been debunked a bit more. I couldn't get it working the way I thought I could, however if you pass a number in hex eg. 000000aa into write_address everything seems to work! All a bit strange, but thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should show the code that prints the number?

Comment: How do you know whether it is printing in decimal or in hex?

Comment: Thanks @immibis, I've added a bit more info

Comment: @immibis When using the vectors return for a value of 10, the output is 00000010. With the code in read_word un-commented we get 0000000a.  This is the same of all numbers when using the return - we get the padding and decimal value

Comment: Are elements of mem initialised to anything?

Comment: @SergeySlepov I'm assumimg `decltype(mem)(1024,0);` is initialising the first 1024 elements to 0, although could be wrong

Comment: Ah, yes, just noticed that. Then why are you getting `00000010` and not `00000000`?

Comment: How about putting all these snippets into one source file, including initialization?  (MCVE)

Comment: @Dave In fact, it would be great to have a `read_word1` and a `read_word2`, the first having the commented `10` and the second uncommented `10`.  Each would be called before calling `show_address`.

Comment: @donjuedo Thanks, I've reordered the question to make things a bit more manageable - hopefully this provides more insight

Comment: @SergeySlepov You're right -I'm using a write function to set the vector, updated the question

Comment: @Dave Are you absolutely sure the value in the vector is 10 (decimal) and not 16 (decimal)? That seems to be the most likely explanation, that it is actually 16.

Comment: @immibis 100% sure. I'd bet my firstborn, and maybe even the next one.

Comment: I'm using cin to get the input for my write function if that makes any difference.

Comment: Could you try and replicate the problem in a cleanroom environment such as http://cpp.sh/?

Comment: What compiler are you using? I think the Microsoft one still doesn't support `j` in printf

Comment: @M.M Gcc version 4.9.2

Comment: What build? There is a version of gcc for windows that passes on printf calls to the microsoft C library that doesn't support `j`

Comment: @m.m Not to sure on the build, is there a terminal function I can use to find it?

Comment: @SergeySlepov Couldn't recreate the error unfortunately, but found a workaround posted in edit, thanks guys

Comment: well, you could test out the printf in a separate program